# How can I read text from a file inside the bundle in Swift?

Tags: swift

I downloaded this code from hackingwithswift.com, but it always fails at loading the file where it says "contents could not be loaded". Does anyone have an idea what might cause this problem? Here's my code:

```
if let filepath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "german", ofType: "dic") {
      do {
        contents = try String(contentsOfFile: filepath)
        print(contents)
      } catch {
        print("contents could not be loaded \(error)")
      }
    } else {
      print("file not found")
    }
      text = contents.components(separatedBy: "\n")
```

It then outputs the error:

```
domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=264 "The file “german.dic” couldn’t be opened because the text encoding of its contents can’t be determined." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/0F0F9BBA-3964-41FA-B5EE-114C64F44189/SchoolAid Pro.app/german.dic}
```

Comment: What's your output? What does it print? There are plenty of reason why it could fails... For instance `print("contents could not be loaded")`=> `print("contents could not be loaded: \(error)")` is much more useful...

Comment: This is the error: domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=264 "The file “german.dic” couldn’t be opened because the text encoding of its contents can’t be determined." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/0F0F9BBA-3964-41FA-B5EE-114C64F44189/SchoolAid Pro.app/german.dic}

Comment: What kind of text file is it? `String(contentsOfFile` can open only  plain text files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved: It seems like Swift just doesn't like the .dic format. After copying the contents of the .dic file and pasting them into a .txt file, everything worked out just fine.